# How to access my single wordpress site via multiple sub-domain

Tags: wordpress

I want to access my single worpress installation site via multiple subdomain without using multisite functionality.

What i have tried, but i have not found the perfect solution:

I have used the MultiDomain plugin but it restricted me to add the multiple domain in array through hardcode, actually i want the subdomain ui plugins that help me to add multiple subdomain like "myname.example.com" to redirect in main wordpress website i.e "example.com".

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can configure that easily in apache using [NameVirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/vhosts/name-based.html), no need for a WordPress plugin.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName *.example.com
  # for a single subdomain:
  #ServerAlias myname.example.com
  Redirect permanent / http://example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

If you don't have direct access to your apache config, you can configure `*.example.com` to it's own document root (how to do that depends on you hoster, can't give you any concrete examples) and configure the redirect in a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```